# CSS gets disturbed after Link is clicked - react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, styled-components

I'm exporting Link as `import { Link } from "react-router-dom"` and in my JSX I have

```
<Link to='/'>Back</Link>
```

when I click `Link`, page renders the data but most `css` is not rendered correctly. I used the material-ui link, but issue still remains the same.

```
import { Link } from "@material-ui/core";
<Link onClick={() => history.push('/')}> Back </Link>
```

app.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./containers/landing_page";
import store from "./store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

PS: if it is helpful I'm using `@material-ui/core` & `styled-components` in my application

Comment: What do you mean by "most css is not rendered correctly." ? Can you please elaborate because `<Link>` doesn't affect css at all. It's either the endpoint to which that `<Link>` routes to doesn't have css configured correctly.

Comment: padding and font size are disturbed. I wish I could share the screenshot but it is private

Comment: this is probably a `css` question. there might be some elements in the route you are proceeding to that is causing the "disturbance" in padding and font size

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the bug was producing because although I fixed that it still doesn't make any sense

**Error Code**

```
{ 
  product ? 
    <Grid>
      <Link to='/'>Back</Link>
      <Product product={product} />
    </Grid> : null
}
```

**Fix**

```
<Grid>
  <Link to='/'>Back</Link>
  {
    product ? <Product product={product} /> : null 
  }
</Grid>
```